# Plotly Waterfall Chart Stacked in Python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, waterfall

All,
I can create a nice little waterfall chart using the code below.  However, I would like to be able to split the data to show contributions to that specific metric.

For example I would like to split the waterfall bars by Local and International.  ie. the Sales would have both Local and International adding up to the total.  Can this be done.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
    name = "20", orientation = "v",
    measure = ["relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total"],
    x = ["Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax"],
    textposition = "outside",
    text = ["+60", "+80", "", "-40", "-20", "Total"],
    y = [60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0],
    connector = {"line":{"color":"rgb(63, 63, 63)"}},
))

fig.update_layout(
        title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
        showlegend = True
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: This would be handled with `layout.waterfallmode` but at the moment we only support side-by-side and overlay, not stacking.

Comment: that is a pity.  I will try to find alternative ways (besides excel:)

Comment: It’s a challenging thing to implement... unclear how to handle cases where parts of the same stack have different signs. I’d love to see how other tools handle it!

Comment: It looks like it is possible on R using ggplot2. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259930/how-to-create-a-stacked-waterfall-chart-in-r)