# How to offset (or unstack) data points within the same date in a Waterfall plotly chart?

Tags: python, charts, plotly, jupyter

After extensive research, the closest I found to my issue was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310163/plotly-waterfall-chart-stacked-in-python).

I'm building a waterfall chart to illustrate the cashflow of a certain company. That being said, I have several cashflow entries on the same date.

Currently I'm using `waterfallmode='overlay'` but I tried `group` as well. I have some trouble in looking at such chart because the positive and negative entries do overlap and it all gets a bit confused.

What I want exactly is: To unstack (or offset) each entries within a day, so that they are located laterally and parallel to each other, as opposed to overlapped or stacked.

The closest settings I found to deal with it, and why they don't work are:

- `waterfallgap` and `waterfallgroupgap` (Creating a `FigureWidget` object)
- `offset` and `offsetgroup`

None of them work because they offset the entire group (as opposed to each entry).

I guess one solution would be to force a minute's difference in each of the Date entries. But I'm sure there is a cleaner solution

Comment: Why don’t you like the “group” option?

Comment: I think that I would need to define each date as a group for that to work

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, that's what you'd need to do. Jittering them a bit would be a good option in this case (the "minute's difference")